# VUE : Updating store data after login

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router, vuex

I'm having an issue where the store data "menus" is not updated after i do a login. 
Appearantly.. the object "loggedInUser" is not sat before i call "getMenus".. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong here...

PS! When debugging in chrome, i notice that loggedInUser is "null" when entering the api call (see api.js codesnippet).

**Login.vue (method) :**

```
methods: {
    doLogin() {
        this.errorMessage = '';
        this.loading = true;
        let userCredentials = {
            'username': this.loginEmail,
            'password': this.loginPassword
        };

        this.$store.dispatch('tryLogin', {
            'login': this.loginEmail,
            'password': this.loginPassword
        }).then((response) => { 
            this.$store.dispatch('getMenus')
                .then((response) => {
                    this.$router.push('/')
            });
        });
    }
```

},

**Menus.vue (same as /)**

```
 computed: {
    menus() {
        return this.$store.getters.menus
    }
    },
    created() {
        this.$store.dispatch('getMenus')
    },
methods: {
    viewMenu: function(item) {
        console.log("=> View Menu : " + item.Name)
        this.$router.push('/viewmenu/' + item.Id)
    }
    }
}
```

**store.js (getMenus action AND tryLogin)**

```
actions: {
    getMenus({ commit, getters }) {
        api.getMenus(getters.loggedInUser)
            .then(menus => {
                commit('UPDATE_MENUS', menus);
            });
    },
    tryLogin({ commit }, credentials) {
        api.tryLogin(credentials)
        .then(loggedInUser => {
            commit('LOGGED_IN_USER', loggedInUser);
        });
    },
```

**api.js (getMenus function)**

```
getMenus(loggedInUser) {
    var hostname = 'http://myurl'

    var config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }
    var endpointUrl = hostname + '/api/Menu/GetMenus';

    if (loggedInUser != null){
        endpointUrl = hostname + '/api/Menu/GetMenusForSubCompany/' + loggedInUser.encryptedsubcompanyid;
    }

    return axios.get(endpointUrl, config)
        .then(response => response.data);
},
```

Answer (score 1):

From your `store.js` snippet, it seems you forget to return the promise.

Comment: ie, `return api.tryLogin(credentials)...`. See https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/actions.html#composing-actions